# How do you integrate a $0$-form?

Tags: calculus, differential-forms

I am trying to learn about differential forms. I know that A $0$-form is just a scalar function $f$. My question is: **How is the integral of a $0$-form defined?**

In particular, if $f$ is a function of one variable (so the usual functions from basic calculus). From regular calculus I understand how to find
$$
\int_a^b f(x)\; dx
$$
but **how does this look like when we use differential forms?**

If $f$ is a $0$-form, then $df$ is a $1$-form, and then I think that
$$
\int_a^b df = f(b) - f(a).
$$
**Is that correct?**

Comment: right, but not all the 1-form $\omega$ are of the type $d\phi$ for some 0-form $\phi$

Comment: That last equation *is* correct, but it's not the integral of a $0$-form, it's the integral of a $1$-form.  To find the integral of a $0$-form over the *boundary* of a curve $C$ (i.e. two "oriented" points) we define $\int_{\partial C}f = f(b) - f(a)$.

Comment: @Bye_World: It seems like you are becoming by go-to guy for differential forms. Would you write up an answer on this? So, what is the equivalent of integrating a scalar function?

Comment: @JohnDoe It seems I don't need to, Micah's given a fine answer.

Comment: @Bye_World: So is it correct to say that if $f$ is a scalar function of one varialbe $x$, then $df = f'(x) dx$, and so $\int df = \int f'(x) dx = f(x)$?

Comment: It's correct to say $\int_C f'(x)dx = \int_C df \stackrel{*}=  \int_{\partial C} f(x) \stackrel{\dagger}= f(b)-f(a)$ where $*$ makes use of Stokes' theorem and $\dagger$ makes use of the definition of the integral of a $0$-form on a discrete set.

Comment: @Bye_World: So we are not thinking about indefinite integrals, but only definite integrals? (That would make sense.)

Comment: Yes.  I'm not sure that indefinite integrals have any meaning when we start generalizing integration.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In terms of differential forms, the standard integration you learned in calculus is actually about integrating $1$-forms: namely, the $1$-forms $f(x) \, dx$.

In general, you integrate $n$-forms over $n$-dimensional manifolds. So a $0$-form would be integrated over a $0$-dimensional manifold: that is, a discrete set of points $P$, taken with orientation (i.e., each point is assigned a sign). We then have

$$\int_P f = \sum_{p \in P} f(p) \sigma(p)$$

where $\sigma(p)$ is the sign assigned to $p$.

Remember that Stokes' theorem for differential forms says that

$$
\int_{\partial M} f = \int_M df
$$
where $\partial M$ is the boundary of the manifold $M$.

If we consider the case where $M$ is the interval $[a,b]$, its boundary consists of the two points $a$ and $b$, where $b$ is given positive sign and $a$ is given negative sign. So Stokes' theorem along with the above definition of zero-dimensional integral says that
$$
\int_{[a, b]} df = \int_{[a, b]} f'(x) \, dx = f(b)-f(a)
$$
which is just the ordinary fundamental theorem of calculus.

Note however that this is not actually helpful for performing integrals! Given a function $g$ on the interval, you still need to find the $f$ such that $g(x) \, dx = df$: that is, such that $f'(x)=g(x)$. This is exactly what you needed to do in order to integrate $g$ before you knew anything about differential forms. The correct way to understand this fact is as the reason why people call the general version of Stokes' theorem an $n$-dimensional generalization of the fundamental theorem of calculus, not as any way to make concrete integration problems easier.

Comment: Would you include a brief description of Stoke's theorem for differential forms?

Comment: @JohnDoe Stokes' theorem is the topic of page $5$ of that pdf you're working through.

Comment: @Bye_World: Ahh.. ok, thanks, I will get to that I guess.

Comment: @Bye_World: Would you take a look at my new question about substitution?

Comment: Beautiful answer. If 0 forms are integrated on 0 manifolds then what do we make of line integrals of scalar fields? Or are they just Steltjie integrals in which the function we are integrating over is somewhat the path?